# Is there a painless way to make a "css sandbox"?

Tags: html, css

By CSS sandbox I mean a section in my layout that have a completely independent look. I need this because some classes of mine need to output some "windows" of content in the layout, but I don't want the app's css to mess with them. They're mostly debug related, like printing var contents, benchmark graphs or displaying some error/exception.

Until now I was doing some kind of local reset, but this gets really annoying to avoid collisions and could fail if I forget some rules. ex:

```
html body div.eh-box {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-size: 100% !important;
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    font: 12px/12px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

html body div.eh-box * {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-size: 100% !important;
    font: inherit !important;
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    color: #333 !important;
}

html body div.eh-box .title {
    font-size: 50px !important;
    line-height: 75px !important;
    /*font-weight: bold !important;*/
}

html body div.eh-box .desc {
    font-size: 24px !important;
    line-height: 36px !important;
}
```

Comment: Create it's own `div`?

Comment: If the app styles any tag (think twitter bootstrap for instance), a simple `div` won't protect my contents from being styled as well.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: Why don't you make an iframe? You could also use a local CSS reset, but that won't stop `!important` properties from leaking through.

Comment: @Blender now that's a good idea (:

Comment: maybe if I put `!important`s in the reset inside... will definetely try that (:

Comment: well, it seems the only way to add inline contents in an iframe is with the `srcdoc` attribute, which only Chrome and Safari supports :(

Comment: I had the same issue when creating an epub reader that was integrated into a site, since the epubs have their own stylesheets, which I didn't want to conflict with the containing site.  For what it's worth, I ended up doing something similar to your post.  I wrote a preprocessor for the epub stylesheets that prefixed a parent selector to all of the rules, which let me keep it effectively isolated to the container.  I was running the epubs through XSLT anyway, so I just modified the stylesheet links to use the preprocessor.

Comment: The properties in this style sheet have SO higher specificity that sure even overwrites css properties from Jon Skeet blog! (Sorry for the spam. Could not resist. Sorry. Shutting up now.)

Comment: I asked a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604800/ignore-override-surrounding-inherited-css

Answer (score 7):

I don't know much about it, but I think thats more or less what [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) does

Comment: wow! That's very neat! If only it wasn't so new and experimental/unsuported. I probably won't be able to use it yet, but anyway, this is awesome. thanks (:

Comment: Yes, great way to solve the problem and meanwhile it's supported, see https://caniuse.com/shadowdomv1

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution - depending on your application, is to load that layout section in an `iframe` - this way its a completely seperate document subject to a seperate set of styles. Not sure if I need to mention that there are certain drawbacks to using frames.

Comment: The drawbacks wouldn't be an issue since it's just for debugging. But this was discussed in the comments and it seems that only chrome and safari supports inline markup in iframe (with the `srcdoc` property). So it wouldn't help much...

Comment: oops, didn't read the comments.  I'm not sure I understand the inline markup thing though. If I were doing it, I would change give the page within the iframe an api of sorts where it displays content based upon GET parameters in the query string. Then you could change `src` of the frame when you want to update the frame's contents `iframe.html?error=display+this+error+text`

Comment: but perhaps a better question is why can't you move most of this debug info to the console? IDK about the graphs... but maybe do these with Canvas?

Comment: Console is not so good to nicely format information (colors, spacing, font-size, etc). And I'm doing web develop, so it's really more convenient to have those info on screen. Canvas is a good idea though, but sounds even more painful :/

Comment: With "inline markup" I mean to display the info in the body of the same request. It would not be nice having to save the info somewhere, just to have another request displaying it.

Comment: Yea, looks like there will be drawbacks no matter what you do. Probably your best bet if not using Shadow Dom or Iframe is to keep your normal CSS as clean and generic as possible. Consider OOCSS perhaps? The better your css is the easier it will be to manage the cascade and handle specificity stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a container element with an ID and then reset its rules (make sure this part is loaded last). The only problem you might encounter then are the `!important` rules, but you can use those in your reset part as well (not really recommended practice, but it will work).

Also, depending on the structure of your site, you might want to call your container element as specific as possible, like `body #top_element #another_top_element #container` in order to give it higher priority, but in most cases this won't be necessary...

Comment: `!important` won’t help against CSS rules that also use `!important` and have higher specificity. But additionally using an `id` attribute for the container and using the corresponding id selector as part of all selectors makes the sandbox practically safe.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yup, that's what I tried to say in my second paragraph.

Comment: that's kinda what i'm doing...perhaps if I use the `*` selector i could ease the proccess? a specific rule with class instead of id would be safe too? because some structures are displayed more than once

Comment: Yes, using `#container_name *` selector will shorten the process a lot. ID has a higher priority than a class, that's why I'd go with an ID.

Comment: i'll keep the question running as this is still kinda paifull, but this was very helpful (: ~ updated my example in the question to reflect these ideas. maybe someone come up with some neat hack :p

Answer (score 0):

There has been a technique called **Scoped CSS**

You can't use it [1] anymore but there is a polyfill [2] you can try.

[1] https://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped

[2] https://github.com/PM5544/scoped-polyfill