# Ignore/override surrounding / inherited CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have this call to add HTML/CSS to an existing page:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.zIndex = 9999999;
div.innerHTML = str;  // some pre-defined HTML string
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
```

I am creating a Chrome Extension that helps developers. What's happening is that the above HTML is inheriting the existing CSS from developer's pages. I want the styling of the above HTML to be independent from the CSS/styling on the developer's page.

Is there a way to ignore all existing CSS on page? I'd like to basically create a "CSS sandbox".

I think one way to create such a sandbox, would be an iframe, but I am looking for a simpler way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `class` to elements which you want to reset..and then apply `all:unset` to that class

[*The `all` CSS shorthand property sets all of an element's properties (apart from unicode-bidi and direction) to their initial or inherited values, or to the values specified in another style sheet origin.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)

---

...`all:unset`

*Specifies that all the element's properties should be changed to their `inherited` values if they inherit by default, or to their initial values if not.(It will ignore all the user agent style too.)*

***Stack Snippet***

```js
let p = document.createElement('p');
p.style.color = "red";
p.innerHTML = "Hello"; // some pre-defined HTML string
p.classList.add("reset");
document.body.insertBefore(p, document.body.firstChild);
```

```css
p {
  background: black;
}

.reset {
  all: unset;
}
```

Comment: so `all: unset` will unset all existing attributes on elements with the reset class? cool

Comment: @Olegzandr yes.....`all:unset` reset all the properties of the selected elements to their initial values if there are no inherited properties...